# How to add subscribe button after Feedzy RSS feed?

Tags: php, wordpress, button, plugins, rss

I'm trying to figure out, how to alter the Feedzy Wordpress RSS widget, which serves to show RSS feed, so that is shows a RSS subscribe button.

I have tried adding my button code a different parts of the HTML part inside of the PHP file, but without any success. While doing that, I was checking the website for any mention of my button code on the web, but nothing.
Could you please suggest, how this can be solved?

Here is the Feedzy RSS PHP:

```
<?php
/**
 * The file that defines the core plugin class
 *
 * A class definition that includes attributes and functions used across both the
 * public-facing side of the site and the admin area.
 *
 * @link       http://themeisle.com
 * @since      3.0.0
 *
 * @package    feedzy-rss-feeds
 * @subpackage feedzy-rss-feeds/form
 */

$html_parts = Feedzy_Rss_Feeds_Ui_Lang::get_form_elements();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Disable browser caching of dialog window -->
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo FEEDZY_ABSURL . 'css/form.css?h=' . date( 'dmYHis' ); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="feedzy-popup-form container">
        <?php
        $output = '';
        if ( ! empty( $html_parts ) ) {
            foreach ( $html_parts as $item => $section ) {
                $output .= '<div class="container feedzy_' . $item . '">';
                $output .= '<h5>' . $section['title'] . '</h5>';
                if ( isset( $section['description'] ) ) {
                    $output .= '<p>' . $section['description'] . '</p>';
                }
                if ( ! empty( $section['elements'] ) ) {
                    foreach ( $section['elements'] as $name => $props ) {
                        $element = '';
                        $disabled = '';
                        $badge = '';
                        if ( isset( $props['disabled'] ) && $props['disabled'] ) {
                            $disabled = 'disabled="true"';
                            $badge = '<small class="feedzy_pro_tag">' . __( 'Premium', 'feedzy-rss-feeds' ) . '</small>';
                        }
                        switch ( $props['type'] ) {
                            case 'select':
                                $element = '<select name="' . $name . '" data-feedzy="' . $name . '" ' . $disabled . ' >';
                                foreach ( $props['opts'] as $opt => $values ) {
                                    $checked = '';
                                    if ( $props['value'] == $values['value'] ) {
                                        $checked = 'selected';
                                    }
                                    $element .= '<option value="' . $values['value'] . '" ' . $checked . ' > ' . $values['label'] . '</option>';
                                }
                                $element .= '</select>';
                                break;
                            case 'radio':
                                foreach ( $props['opts'] as $opt => $values ) {
                                    $checked = '';
                                    if ( $props['value'] == $values['value'] ) {
                                        $checked = 'checked="checked"';
                                    }
                                    $element .= '<label class="feedzy-radio-image feedzy-template-' . $values['value']
                                                . '"><input type="radio" name="' . $name . '" data-feedzy="' . $name . '" value="' . $values['value'] . '" ' . $checked . ' ' . $disabled . ' />' .
                                                $values['label'] . '</label>';
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'checkbox':
                                foreach ( $props['opts'] as $opt => $values ) {
                                    $checked = '';
                                    if ( $props['value'] == $values['value'] ) {
                                        $checked = 'checked="checked"';
                                    }
                                    $element .= '<input type="checkbox" name="' . $name . '" data-feedzy="' . $name . '" value="' . $values['value'] . '" ' . $checked . ' ' . $disabled . ' /> ' . $values['label'];
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'file':
                                $element = '
                                    <input type="text" class="column column-50 float-left" name="' . $name . '" data-feedzy="' . $name . '" id="feedzy_image_url" placeholder="' . $props['placeholder'] . '" value="' . $props['value'] . '">
                                    <input type="button" class="column column-50 float-right button-outline" name="upload-btn" id="feedzy_upload_btn" value="' . $props['button']['button_text'] . '">
                                ';
                                break;
                            default:
                                $element = '<input type="text" name="' . $name . '" data-feedzy="' . $name . '" value="' . $props['value'] . '" placeholder="' . $props['placeholder'] . '" ' . $disabled . ' />';
                                break;
                        }
                        $output .= '
                        <div class="row feedzy_element_' . $name . '">
                           <div class="column column-50">
                                <label for="' . $name . '">' . $props['label'] . $badge . '</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column column-50">
                                ' . $element . '
                            </div>
                            <hr/>
                        </div>
                        ';
                    }
                }
                $output .= '</div>';
            }
        }
        echo $output;
        ?>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var args = top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.getParams();
        var $ = args.jquery;
        var editor = args.editor;
        var wp = args.wp;
        var custom_uploader;
        $(document).ready(function($) {
            $(document).on('click', '#feedzy_upload_btn', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var upload_button = $(this);
                custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
                    title: editor.getLang( 'feedzy_tinymce_plugin.image_button' ),
                    button: {
                        text: editor.getLang( 'feedzy_tinymce_plugin.image_button' )
                    },
                    multiple: false
                });

                custom_uploader.on('select', function () {
                    var attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
                    upload_button.siblings('input[type="text"]').val(attachment.url);
                });

                custom_uploader.open();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the HTML of my subscribe button:

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.rmol.cz/novinky/rss">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Přihlásit k odběru</button>
</form>
```

Thank you for any suggestions.